# git: ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: name (jquery) when push to production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried `git push` to a hosting service (not heroku). I typed the following commands on Windows.

`rake assets:precompile`
`git add .`
`git commit -m "xxx"`
`git push origin master`

Then the following error is displayed on the hosting service screen.

```
I, [2014-11-08T09:28:48.280141 #22295]  INFO -- : Writing /var/repos/xxx/xxx/public/assets/noimage-9f9de98ce95d5c9108e75feb33a04e35.gif
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: name (jquery) (line: 12946, col: 8, pos: 364216)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:2316:10736)
    at js_error (<eval>:2316:10955)
    at croak (<eval>:2316:18665)
    at token_error (<eval>:2316:18802)
    at unexpected (<eval>:2316:18890)
    at semicolon (<eval>:2316:19363)
    at simple_statement (<eval>:2316:21849)
    at <eval>:2316:20090
    at <eval>:2316:19536
    at <eval>:2316:31209
  (in /var/repos/xxx/xxx/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)/var/repos/xxx/xxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:34:in `rescue in block in eval'
/var/repos/xxx/xxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:28:in `block in eval'
/var/repos/xxx/xxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:80:in `block in lock'
/var/repos/xxx/xxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/lib/v8/c/locker.rb:13:in `Locker'
/var/repos/xxx/xxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in `lock'
/var/repos/xxx/xxx/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:27:in `eval'
    .
    .
    .
```

Although there is the file name `noimage-9f9de98ce95d5c9108e75feb33a04e35.gif` on the first line of the error message, I saved `app\assets\images\noimage.gif` locally.

Does this have something to do with the error?

There are some files in `\app\assets\javascripts`.

**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
require jquery.turbolinks
```

**calendars.js.coffee**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
$(document).ready( ->
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow')
)
```

There are some other js.coffee files, but they don't have any code as below.

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `noimage-9f9de98ce95d5c9108e75feb33a04e35.gif` is a red herring--that's just the last successful log line before the error.

That `require` statement at the end of your application.js should have a leading `//=`, I believe. It's definitely not valid JS as written.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Andrew Lorente. I edit `//= require jquery.turbolinks` and execute `rake assets:precompile`, but rake aborted as followings: `rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.turbolinks'
  (in e:/shu/rails/xxx/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`
Any other advice you can give me?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Andrew Lorente. I didn't install `jquery-turbolinks`. So I add `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` in Gemfile and execute `bundle install`. I also edit `//= require jquery.turbolinks` in application.js as you advised. After that, it works!